# Why do I have diiferent fields displaying when I view disp.aspx vs. edit.aspx forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have 10 fields in a content type call Intake that I use within a Document library.  I have hidden 5 fields.  When I click on edit.aspx 5 fields display as expected.  However, when I click on view properties for some reason 6 fields display.  How is this possible..Note the field displaying that I do no not want displayed is a lookup field where as part of the column properties other columns display.

Would like to see how I can not have this field displayed when I click on Edit Properties...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new EditForm through designer and see how many fields getting displayed

Comment: Hi John, unfortunately I do not have designer,,any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ShowInDisplayForm` property of the particular field to false in order to hide it from the Display form. Here is a sample PowerShell code to do this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://Yoursite
$list = $web.Lists["YourListTitle"] 
$field = $list.Fields["FieldDisplayName"]
$filed.ShowInDisplayForm = $false
$field.Update()
```